# Getting directory path to .class file containing main

Tags: java, file, path

Is it possible to get the path to my .class file containing my main function from within main?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know where the .class file resides on the file system?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
URL main = Main.class.getResource("Main.class");
if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(main.getProtocol()))
  throw new IllegalStateException("Main class is not stored in a file.");
File path = new File(main.getPath());
```

Note that most class files are assembled into JAR files so this won't work in every case (hence the `IllegalStateException`). However, you can locate the JAR that contains the class with this technique, and you can get the content of the class file by substituting a call to `getResourceAsStream()` in place of `getResource()`, and that will work whether the class is on the file system or in a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/java/donnie/java-main.html, no.  However, I suggest reading [$0 (Program Name) in Java? Discover main class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894/0-program-name-in-java-discover-main-class) , which at least gives you the main class .

Comment: Within the `main` method, the enclosing class is already known.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need it for? If you need it to get hold of any files that are in the same directory, that's what [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) is for.

Comment: trying to get a lock on my main class file in order to stop launching of my application more than once.

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like an end-user issue to me.  Also consider the possible need to run multiple instances of any given application, and preventing users from doing so is going to become a major annoyance.

If the problem is with temporary file conflicts, then just make sure all your temporary files have unique names.  This, as I understand it, is the most common reason people feel a need to prevent multiple instances of their applications from running.

P.S.:  The java.io.File.createTempFile() methods are ideally suited for preventing temporary file conflicts because they automatically generate unique filenames.