# copying in same directory of the project in java?

Tags: java, copying

```
int reval = fcCari.showOpenDialog(this);
String sourcePath = fcCari.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
String targetPath = "C:\\Users\\nadzar\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JavaSQLite\\resource\\";
    targetPath += fcCari.getSelectedFile().getName();
    if ((reval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)) {
            File source = new File(sourcePath);
            File target = new File(targetPath);
            copyFile(source, target);
            targetPathFoto=targetPath;
            tambahFoto(targetPathFoto);
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Batal Menambahkan Foto");
        tambahFoto(this.targetFoto);
    }
    System.out.println(targetPathFoto);
```

If my project has moved, the path must be changed.
I ask how can the target path change while my project directory has changed?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778187/getting-directory-path-to-class-file-containing-main)?

Answer (score 0):

Use properties file for this purpose, what you need to do is change the property value.

```
# app home, build absolute paths in code using this path
app.home=path_to_home_directory
```

Use [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to read these properties.

See examples at [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

Comment: how if my project's directory changed?if i clean and build the program?

Comment: if you change your directory, you will update `app.home` in your properties file