# How to get the path of running java program

Tags: java

Is there a way to get the path of main class of the running java program.

structure is

```
D:/
|---Project
       |------bin
       |------src
```

I want to get the path as `D:\Project\bin\`.

I tried `System.getProperty("java.class.path");` but the problem is, if I run like

```
java -classpath D:\Project\bin;D:\Project\src\  Main

Output 
Getting : D:\Project\bin;D:\Project\src\
Want    : D:\Project\bin
```

Is there any way to do this?

---

---

**=====  EDIT  =====**

*Got the **solution** here*

[**Solution 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227569/2260473) (By [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet))

```
package foo;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassLoader loader = Test.class.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(loader.getResource("foo/Test.class"));
    }
}
```

This printed out:

```
file:/C:/Users/Jon/Test/foo/Test.class
```

[**Solution 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/778246/2260473) (By [Erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474/erickson))

```
URL main = Main.class.getResource("Main.class");
if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(main.getProtocol()))
  throw new IllegalStateException("Main class is not stored in a file.");
File path = new File(main.getPath());
```

Note that most class files are assembled into JAR files so this won't work in every case (hence the `IllegalStateException`). However, you can locate the JAR that contains the class with this technique, and you can get the content of the class file by substituting a call to `getResourceAsStream()` in place of `getResource()`, and that will work whether the class is on the file system or in a JAR.

Comment: Well you could always tokenize the result (cut around the ";" which seperate the entries).
The classpath property usually contains several entries (e.g. libraries you are using and so on).
Maybe you should rethink your requirements. If you are just interested in one folder, are you sure parsing the classpath is a good idea?

Comment: @Matthias Please note that the path separator is different on different platforms. It is better to use `System.getProperty("path.separator");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/778246/1862502

Comment: As always with this type of question.  ***Why?***  What actual application feature are you trying to implement?  Serialization of settings, a 'self uninstaller'..?

Comment: @AndrewThompson : actually the code is using some files from the Directory. But if I use "../.." then one/two ant build located in different directory is getting failed. By getting path at runtime, this problem is solved. Please tell if there is any easy way to prevent that.

Comment: *"actually the code is using some files from the Directory."*  What files?  What are they used for?   Are they read only or read/write?

Comment: @AndrewThompson : some files to read, some files to write. and the files are located in different locations.  ie. if .class is in D:/Work/Hello/Code/bin/  then files are in D:/Work/Hello/Image/ ; D:/Work/Hello/Code/File ; like that..  So I need D:/Work/Hello/Code/ at runtime, as this path may change if someone store the /Hello/ directory somewhere else.

Comment: Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".")

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this code:

```
final File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

replace '`MyClass`' with your class containing the main method.

Alternatively you can also use

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

Above mentioned System property provides

> Path used to find directories and JAR archives containing class files.
>   Elements of the class path are separated by a platform-specific
>   character specified in the path.separator property.

Comment: getCodeSource() returns null in my jvm (jetty)

Comment: would `MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` be not just sufficient? Why creating a `File` object?

Answer (score 145):

Use

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

You can also split it into it's elements easily

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String[] classpathEntries = classpath.split(File.pathSeparator);
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer the question to be honest. The system property 'java.class.path' returns the whole classpath, JAR's and everything. The OP is asking for the path to the running main class (working directory).

Comment: The working directory is not necessarily where the class files are ran from. The example the OP gave proves this. While this answer does include all the locations of the project components, he shows how you can separate them into their elements.

Comment: @monzonj I agree with you. The question evolved after I answered it. Thus my answer did not match anymore. But in the meanwhile a lot of people found that answer useful, because it fits to the headline. That's why I still keep it and do not delete it.

Answer (score 27):

You actually do not want to get the path to your main class. According to your example you want to get the current working directory, i.e. directory where your program started. In this case you can just say `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: From all answers this is the most accurate

Answer (score 3):

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

    for(URL url: urls){
        System.out.println(url.getFile());
    }
```

Comment: this usually should give you just the path from where your application was started. This does not need to be where your main class is located at all.

Comment: There is also no guarantee the system classloader is a `URLClassLoader` either :P

Comment: This was useful for me. Thanks

Comment: ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader