# Can not debug java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions

Tags: java, file-upload, openstack-swift, jclouds

I am trying to make an applet for uploading files to openstack swift using jclouds.
And I am facing the NoClassDefFoundError, following is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions
    at org.nnsoft.guice.rocoto.configuration.ConfigurationModule.configure(ConfigurationModule.java:64)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:92)
    at org.nnsoft.guice.rocoto.Rocoto.expandVariables(Rocoto.java:52)
    at org.nnsoft.guice.rocoto.Rocoto.expandVariables(Rocoto.java:47)
    at org.jclouds.config.BindPropertiesToExpandedValues.configure(BindPropertiesToExpandedValues.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.expandProperties(ContextBuilder.java:385)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:320)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:620)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:600)
    at com.cdac.appletclass.Test.main(Test.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 21 more
```

I googled for `com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions`, and came to know that it is part of guice-3.0.jar.
But guice-3.0.jar is already there in my project.
How to debug then? any help..???

Comment: Did you add it to android dependencies?

Comment: it is likely to be a conflict between several guice versions. Are you sure to have only guice-3.0 on your classpath ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest printing out what's on your classpath from within your app (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-class-path-of-running-java-program/17541055#17541055)). That way you'll know exactly what classpath your app is using, if there's anything missing or any collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved now.
It was a mistake between guice 3.0 and guice-3.0.0, because both are having the same maven artifact-id but group-id was different.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Open the property of your project and add a dependency library.

Comment: It is not an android application. It is a normal java class library project in netbeans having all required jars and libraries in included in lib folder of the project.

Comment: Did it run on the same machine?