# Java & SQLite - another ClassNotFoundexception

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, classpath, classnotfound

I am working with Eclipse (running on Windows 8.1) and want to access to a sqlite database. Sadly im not able to work with the driver even though I defined its location on the CLASSPATH environment varible. 
The following program is from one of the thousand tutorial sites:

```
package sqliteconnectiontest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // register the driver
    String sDriverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    Class.forName(sDriverName);

    // now we set up a set of fairly basic string variables to use in the
    // body of the code proper
    String sTempDb = "hello.db";
    String sJdbc = "jdbc:sqlite";
    String sDbUrl = sJdbc + ":" + sTempDb;
    // which will produce a legitimate Url for SqlLite JDBC :
    // jdbc:sqlite:hello.db
    int iTimeout = 30;
    String sMakeTable = "CREATE TABLE dummy (id numeric, response text)";
    String sMakeInsert = "INSERT INTO dummy VALUES(1,'Hello from the database')";
    String sMakeSelect = "SELECT response from dummy";

    // create a database connection
    System.out.println(sDbUrl);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sDbUrl);
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            stmt.setQueryTimeout(iTimeout); 
            stmt.executeUpdate(sMakeTable);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sMakeInsert);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sMakeSelect);
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String sResult = rs.getString("response");
                    System.out.println(sResult);
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

i already downloaded the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar driver from http://www.xerial.org/maven/repository/artifact/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.2/

The driver is located in:

```
B:\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

My .class File:

```
B:\Progs\Java\sqlconnectiontest\bin\sqliteconnectiontest\test.class
```

The CLASSPATH environment variable:

```
CLASSPATH=B:\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar;
```

When I'm trying to execute the program this exception gets thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sqliteconnectiontest.test.main(test.java:14)
```

From what i found across the internet this problem should mean that the JDBC-driver could not be found, though i put its direction on the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Add   `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`
 before `Class.forName` and check if your `jar` directory is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is thrown by the `Classl¡Loader` when it is unable to find the required class.

It can be caused by two problems:

a) The class you're searching for is not inside the JAR file (you can check it uncompressing the jar).

b) You're not using the CLASSPATH you think.

Could you get sure the CLASSPATH the ClassLoader uses is the same you're setting?

In [How to get the path of running java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-class-path-of-running-java-program) you can find how to get current CLASSPATH of a running JVM instance.

Comment: i uncompressed the jar-File before, the class is indeed there. So we can cancel "a)".

Comment: Then check the real Classpath

Comment: Use: `String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String[] classpathEntries = classpath.split(File.pathSeparator);` to get it

Comment: I used "Solution 1" from the link you posted above. I get the following output: file:/B:/Progs/Java/sqlconnectiontest/bin/sqliteconnectiontest/test.class

Comment: String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path"); String[] classpathEntries = classpath.split(File.pathSeparator); <-- returns B:\Progs\Java\sqlconnectiontest\bin

Comment: Only one entry? As you can see, it doesn't contain the required JAR. So, it is NOT in the CLASSPATH. How are you executing your file?

Comment: via "Run Test" in Eclipse and/or per "java test" in "B:\Progs\Java\sqliteconnectiontest\bin\sqliteconnectiontest". If I start it in CommandLine, i get an NoClassDefFoundError on System.out.println(loader.getResource("sqliteconnectiontest/test.class"));

Comment: I did nothing like that - because i wanted to get the right access with the classpath env. vars

Comment: I don't know the exact procedure with Eclipse, but I'm sure that you must tell your project the jars it have to include in the CLASSPATH. It doesn't use the environment CLASSPATH.

Comment: I know this topic is very old, but anyway.. i have not been able to fix the problem by using the env. vars; Its indeed very simple to solve the problem by configuring the build-path in eclipse. It took a little time finding out how to do it, but now it works just fine. Thanks for your help.