# Problems Java web service

Tags: java, web-services

I want to learn web services. Tried to create a project for example http://habrahabr.ru/post/148403/. It seems everything is set up. Tomcat run from IDE. error
I want to learn web services. Tried to create a project for example http://habrahabr.ru/post/148403/. It seems everything is set up. Tomcat run from IDE. error

Console:

```
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloService' did not find a matching property.
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1851 ms
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1972 ms
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet service-ws as unavailable
Apr 24, 2014 12:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet service-ws
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:752)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <display-name>HelloService</display-name>
  <description>HelloService</description>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>service-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>service-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Pleaese, help me

Comment: You are missing a Spring dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath to contain not found class

`org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet`

You can view current classpath by getting it thorugh system property as

`System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

If you want to find jar file you can use example as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540996/1960769) like

`final File f = new File(org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());`

Possibly you've missed this jar

`org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.M2.jar`