# Where is My Classpath in Windows?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, classpath

Hello I am using IntelliJ Idea 13.0.1 and I downloaded the seaGlass LAF. The website instructed me to put it into my classpath but I have no idea where that is on my windows machine. I am not using a special package or anything. I'm just using the src folder and I tried putting the JAR file everywhere. No working. Can I get some help please. A SIMPLE classpath explanation would be good too.

Comment: Rather than putting everything in your resources into particular paths on the system, each Java app. should **define its own class-path** to point to those resources.

Comment: @user3600523 for love of Moses, do some research .look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: thank you but how do i configure me own classpath?

Comment: *"how do i configure me own classpath?"*  Each IDE has a different way to allow you to set the class-path.  I don't use IntelliJ, but try F-1 (for searching help) 'class path' enter.  Tip: Add @KickButtowski (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for notifying me, yet sometimes it does not work for me :_)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the path of running java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-path-of-running-java-program)

Comment: look I know you guys are advanced but all I want is to change my look and feel and I want the default classpath so I can drop the LAF jar into it. I dont want a lecture please. I can learn that later. I want just a straight answer. Can anyone provide that

Comment: *"I dont want a lecture please."*  Some things are not so simple they can be summed up in a handful of sentences.  But it is not very helpful to specify how others should reply to you. If you were paying me (us) sure, *but **you're not.***

Comment: @AndrewThompson I actually got the answer right here on the site. It was so simple. Thank you guys for your help. I'm sorry I came off a bit ungrateful. I don't know what I would do without you guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding dependencies in IntelliJ you are in turn configuring the classpath of your application.

1. Create a java project in IntelliJ
2. Open the Project Structure | [Module Dependency](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/dependencies-tab.html)
3. Add your jar for seaglass LAF to the dependency list in the dialog
4. Add your java code to the project
5. Add the code for applying the seaglass LAF to your program

As you start your application the IDE will generate the java execution with the appropriate classpath.  This classpath is created from the list of dependencies, one of which is your LAF.  You can inspect the java program execution with the classpath parameter in the console output in the lower window in the IDE.

There are much better places than here to learn about what a [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) is.