# How to read a text file (or image file) which I kept in the same directory where my java class belong?

Tags: java, android, file

I have a requirement to read a text or image file via java in android. The text and image file is in the same directory of a sub directory inside a *java package*, like;

```
handler    <---- Package
MyClass.java
-----/imgs
---------/test.jpg
```

Now how to get access of `test.jpg` file?

I tried;

```
URL url = OneOfYourClass.class.getResource("handler/imgs/test.jpg");
```

And

```
URL path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("imgs/test.png");
```

None of those worked. Is it permission issue? Does images goes with the apk when I installed the app? Or I am doing wrong something?

I tried for an hours, any help will be great for me.

Comment: Use `assets` instead .

Comment: Yes that can be done, what I am trying is it possible at all?

Comment: You need permission from android 6.0 and above

Comment: I have file read and write permission. And I am getting file not found exception.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-path-of-running-java-program .

Comment: Did not work for me