# Printing Class path of the current working class

Tags: java, classpath

The second answer from: [How to get the path of running java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540942/how-to-get-the-path-of-running-java-program) says I can use:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")"
```

So I tried it:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        System.getproperty("java.class.path");
    }
}
```

But it throws me this error:

```
HelloWorld.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                System.getproperty("java.class.path");
                      ^
  symbol:   method getproperty(String)
  location: class System
1 error
```

Can someone help me how to get to print the class path beside using the command:

```
final File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

Comment: get**p**roperty, should be get**P**roperty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a capital `P`:

```
System.getProperty(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. But It's not printing the class path yet. It only prints 'Hello World'. I am not sure what I am missing out here :(