# Why - JsonParseException: Unexpected character '\' (code 92); expected a quote character enclosing value for 'version'?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to use XMLMapper and readTree() to parse an XML document that is in a String variable named "message".   My code basically does the following:

```
            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(); 

        JsonNode node = null;
        try {
            node = xmlMapper.readTree(message.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            parseLogger.error("------+++++ parse(): - **EXCEPTION** - e=[" + e + "]");
        }
```

For a (really LONG) while, when I ran the app, it wasn't outputting any error or anything, then I was guessing the problem was that it didn't like the XML prolog at the beginning of the message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

So I added the following, to try to escape the double-quotes in the prolog;

```
message = message.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

(FYI, there are no double-quotes in the message, other than the ones that are in the XML prolog line)

and now, the modified prolog line looks like:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>
```

and it is getting past the xmlMapper.readTree(message.getBytes), but I am still getting this error message:

```
JsonParseException: Unexpected character '\' (code 92); expected a quote character enclosing value for 'version'
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,15,"N/A"]]
```

The XML prolog looks all right/OK now (to me), so I don't understand why it is still complaining about the "unexpected ''"?  Also, I am wondering about the part of the error message where it way "N/A"?

Can someone tell me why I am still getting that error?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT1: Here's an example of one of the XML messages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<record>
  <rule>
    <customer>1234</customer>
    <schemaName>schema_name</schemaName>
    <schemaVersion>1.0</schemaVersion>
  </rule>
  <identifier>
    <XXX_USR_PN_IDXXX>12345</XXX_USR_PN_IDXXX>
  </identifier>
  <aRecord>
    <XXX_USR_PN_ID>12345</XXX_USR_PN_ID>
    <UserName>
      <ENTPR_USER_NM_TX>Epple.12345</ENTPR_USER_NM_TX>
    </UserName>
    <person>
      <ADM_ORG_CD>urn</ADM_ORG_CD>
      <XXX_ASSOC_CD>urn:V01</XXX_ASSOC_CD>
      <XXX_OCC_CD>123</XXX_OCC_CD>
      <JB_XXX_OCC_CD>456</JB_XXX_OCC_CD>
      <EMA>johna@mail.com</EMA>
      <ORG_CD>11</ORG_CD>
      <PERSONA_TYP_CD>JUNK122:GOOD321</PERSONA_TYP_CD>
      <PG_CD>07</PG_CD>
      <XYZEC_TYP_CD>12</XYZEC_TYP_CD>
      <XYZ_CAT_CD>G</XYZ_CAT_CD>
    </person>
    <location>
      <CTRY_CD>Yes</CTRY_CD>
    </location>
  </aRecord>
</record>
```

EDIT 2:  One of my colleagues found the problem (and solution).  He referenced this other SO thread:

[NoSuchMethodError on com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480470/nosuchmethoderror-on-com-fasterxml-jackson-dataformat-xml-xmlmapper-coercionconf)

in particular the comment from Marek F, "Marek F
Apr 13, 2022 at 10:44".

My understanding was that the OUD product was already using the 2.9.9 libs, so we had to add dependencies to the pom.xml to the 2.9.9 versions explicitly, and I think he did something to the Jenkins side also and then I rebuilt and it worked.

Comment: I don’t think you should escape the XML prolog.  But where is the JSON where he is complaining about?

Comment: *"it wasn't outputting any error or anything,"* - so perhaps it was actually working?

Comment: Before I added that code to escape the XML prolog, when I tested, it was doing the call to the readTree() but it wasn't logging any errors or anything (I have had tons of debug logging everything and try-catches all over and it never hit any of those.  That was what I was referring to when I said "a LONG WHILE" :).  To answer your question.. none of the output that I as seeing gave me the info to answer your question.

Comment: Can you show us the input that caused this? (BTW, escaping the XML prologue will not help)

Comment: @forty-two - I've edited the original post with an example XML.

Comment: @ArfurNarf - Sorry I missed your comment.  I didn't go into details, but what I doing with the Jackson stuff that I'm posting about is used in a larger context, basically I am using (or trying to use) it for processing some XML messages in a plugin for an LDAP server (Oracle OUD), and so, from the higher level perspective, no, the XML is not being processed correctly so it causes the LDAP requests to fail.  I think what is currently happening is that the readTree() is failing and basically returning null for the node...

Comment: It's complaining about some JSON, not about XML. You haven't mentioned any JSON is your question. Find the JSON, and you will find the error.

Comment: I can read the XML using XmlMapper #readTree() without any issues (well, the name of the root element is lost, maybe there is some config needed, never used XmlMapper before)

Comment: BTW, why not use a proper XML parser? Conversion between XML and JSON is not without issues.

Comment: HI - FYI, we were able to resolve the problem and I just added an EDIT 2 to the original post with information.  THANKS every one for the help and suggestions!