# Unable to read simple text file Java

Tags: java, text, filenotfoundexception, file-read

Hi I've been asked to write code that will read a text file in the same directory as my .class file. I've written a simple program that reads "input.text" and saves it to a string.

```
/** Import util for console input **/
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/** Standard Public Declarations **/
public class costing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Coursework/input.txt"));
        String name = inFile.next();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Gives the error:

```
10: error: unreported expection FileNotFoundExcpetion; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I've tried `input.txt` in the same folder and one level above but still no luck.

Thanks!!

Comment: Surround your Scanner class in a try/catch block..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two types of exception - unchecked and checked.
checked are the ones that are checked at compile time. So, when compiler says 
"10: error: unreported expection `FileNotFoundExcpetion`; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
It means  line `inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));` throws checked exception which means that this method has an underlying risk that it can throw a `FileNotFoundException`and hence you should handle it. So, wrap your code in try/catch block -

```
/** Import util for console input **/
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/** Standard Public Declarations **/
public class costing
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  Scanner inFile;
  try {
     inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Coursework/input.txt"));
     String name = inFile.next();
     System.out.println(name);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

It might throw a runtime error if it did not find input.txt in the correct directory.

Comment: Thanks works now, I also understand why it was happening which is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an exeption in your code put your code between:

```
try
{

  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Coursework/input.txt"));

  String name = inFile.next();

  System.out.println(name);

}

catch( FileNotFoundExcpetion e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this returns "error cannot find symbol catch(FileNotFoundException e)"

Answer (score 0):

put your code in **try ctach** blocks the code :**Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Coursework/input.txt"));** is throws an exception and toy should handle it before compiling your code

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet to get your .class directory:

```
URL main = Main.class.getResource("Main.class");
  if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(main.getProtocol()))
  throw new IllegalStateException("Main class is not stored in a file.");
  File path = new File(main.getPath());
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(path + "/input.txt"));
  String name = inFile.next();
  System.out.println(name);
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778187/getting-directory-path-to-class-file-containing-main).