# "$0 (Program Name) in Java? Discover main class?" again

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I have found following question:
[$0 (Program Name) in Java? Discover main class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894/0-program-name-in-java-discover-main-class)
but accepted answer fails in this situation:

```
public class Derived extends Base { }

class Base {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(getTheClassName());
    }

    static String getTheClassName(){
        StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement main = stack[stack.length - 1];
        return main.getClassName();
    }
}
```

When calling:

```
java Derived
```

the output is unfortunately `Base` not `Derived` as expected.

Is it possible to get the name of *real* main class? (btw. `jps` tool detects main class correctly but to get the proper name I need to know ID of current VM, and that is also a problem)

Best regards.

**Edit:** to be precise: I need to know what is the name of class passed as command line argument passed to JVM. `jps` tools does it the way I want, but I cannot use this tool because of other problems (such as unknown VMid).

**Edit2:** replying globally to **Thorbjørn's** answer:

> For your approach to work, you need to have a non-static method instead. Make it
>   non-static, have a main() in Derived doing a new Derived().getTheClassName()

I am wondering I can get the name without implementing main method in Derived class.

**Solution:** I will provide both (Thorbjørn's and erickson's) mechanisms of an initialization of `Derived` class ;-) All of the answers were very helpful. I accepted Thorbjørn's becase he posted his answer earlier than erickson. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static methods belong to the class they are defined in, and not the instance of the class (same as static/non-static methods).  Hence when you are inside getTheClassName you are in a static method defined in the Base class.

For your approach to work, you need to have a non-static method instead.  Make it non-static, have a main() in Derived doing a new Derived().getTheClassName()

Comment: I know the workaround You have posted, but I am wondering I can get the name without implementing `main` method in `Derived` class.

Comment: To my best of knowledge this is not possible in pure Java.  You might, however, be able to ask HotSpot about this either through JMX or JVM-specific methods, but that would be a vendor specific solution.  Why do you need this?

Comment: I need this for some kind of a app-framework: I will provide an implementation of main method; the user of framework will only  derive from `Base` class and will be able to run his/her class with my *boosted* `main`.

Comment: Tell the users to have a `public static void main(String[] args) { Your.Boosted.Main.main(args); } ` snippet in their Base-derived class.  But frankly I think you should ask the user to provide a Derived instance to your boosted main(..)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect `Derived` when the `main` entry-point is in `Base`? Members that are declared `static` belong to their *class* and are not inherited. When running the program as is, the class `Derived` will not even be loaded, as it is never referenced.

---

Consider taking the derived class's name as an argument to the `Base` class. In addition to making the target class explicit, it might be a convenient place to implement other features.

```
class Base {
  public static void main(String... argv) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clz = Class.forName(argv[0]);
    Method mth = clz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    String[] sub = new String[argv.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(argv, 1, sub, 0, sub.length);
    mth.invoke(null, sub);
  }
}
```

Comment: I expect `Derived`, because as I said, `jps` tools prints `Derived` to the `stdout`. To be precise: I need to know, what class (or class file) was initially passed as command line parameter to `java` command.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that the launcher accepts `Derived` as the class name, since it does not contain a `main` method. The `jps` utility must be accessing the `argv[0]` information passed to the native C `main` method.

Comment: I have glanced into implementation - it uses `MonitoredHost`, and `MonitoredVm` classes.

Comment: Just to be clear: in my example the `Derived` class will be loaded into memory, since I can execute some code inside the `static` block inside the class declaration.

Comment: Those are implementation dependent.

Comment: @Dejw - yes, I experimented a bit with the Oracle `java` launcher and saw what is happening. `Derived` is loaded, but it isn't on the stack, since the entry point is actually in `Base`. However, if you aren't willing to require any special code in `Derived`, you won't be able to take advantage of the fact that it does get loaded.

Comment: Only advantage I need is the name of the class ;-) Nevertheless, thank You for Your answers - they were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : System.getenv().entrySet()){
    if(entry.getKey().startsWith("JAVA_MAIN_CLASS"))
        return entry.getValue();
}
```

But still you should look at others answers. Even if this works, it's a really bad practice.